# More than one configuration of delegated authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, delegated-authentication

I'm working on a project multi-language and multi-country. We use Magento for delegated authentication; in Salesforce we can configure only a url for the delegated authentication, is it possible to configure more than one url for delegated authentication (delegated gateway url)?

Comment: I don't know if you can have multiple urls in Salesforce but if your using Magento theoretically you could create some "proxy" code on your magento server so rather than using the magento authentication only you could check the magento service and if that fails to authenticate the user then tries your second url.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Francis for the answer. I'm waiting for other answers.